# set Object Mapper SerializationFeature in spring configuration

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to configure my Jackson (2.7.4) to indent output  (pretty print) in my Spring (4.2.6) MVC  controllers.

I have controllers that have the @ResponseBody that of course converts to JSON.  I am using a context.xml file.  I have this so far:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
                    <!---  WHAT GOES HERE -->
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

I want to set configure(SerializationFeature f, boolean state) of the ObjectMapper like this:

```
configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, TRUE)
```

How do I do this in my spring context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean to configure ObjectMapper instance

Example

```
<property name="objectMapper">
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
        p:failOnEmptyBeans="false"
        p:indentOutput="true">
        <!-- Other properties -->
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: And we have a winner!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking somthing like this?

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.kulhade.config.CustomObjectMapper">
                    <constructor-arg type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature" value="INDENT_OUTPUT"/>
                    <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Below will be CustomObjectMapper

```
   public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper{

    public CustomObjectMapper(SerializationFeature feature,boolean value) {
        this.configure(feature, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Bean property 'featuresToEnable' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: @mmaceachran I have edited the code. Please check with it.

Comment: @mmaceachran There is another way to do it with CustomObjectMapper. As there is no constructor in jackson's ObjectMapper where we can give constructor arguments I have created the customObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring properties that need to be specified as enum values (such as the list of featuresToDisable) instead of as strings, I found that this worked.

This is similar to the answer from sangram-jadhav, but instead of using the `p:` format that can only accept strings, we use property elements, and we use the `util:constant` element to specify an enum value.

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper">
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
            <property name="featuresToDisable">
              <list>
                <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS"/>
                <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS"/>
              </list>
            </property>
          </bean>
       </property>
      </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
  </mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```